# Sort both columns and rows of a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, sorting

I have two dataframes with same values but different column order and index.

```
df1=
index   col1    col2    col3   col4
----------------------------------
0       1       2017    1.3   1
1       2       2017    2.4   1
2       3       2017    3.5   0
3       1       2018    3.5   0


df2=
index   col3    col1    col2    col4
------------------------------------
0       1       2018    3.5     0
1       3       2017    3.5     0
2       1       2017    1.3     1
3       2       2017    2.4     1
```

Is there a way to transform one so that one becomes identical to the other?

I have found a way to sort columns

```
df1 = df1[df2.columns]
```

but I don't find a way to reorder rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
df1.sort_values(by='col3') # change to the column you want to sort the rows by
```

You can use a list to sort by multiple columns

```
df1.sort_values(by=df2.columns)
df1.sort_values(by=['col3', 'col4'])
```

By default, `sort_values` sorts in ascending order. If you want the rows to be sorted in descending order you can use something like this:

```
df1.sort_values(by=['col3', 'col4'], ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `by=df2.columns` doesn't work with another dataset unless you modify in `by=df2.columns.tolist()`. I have also added a `.reset_index()` so that both dataframes have same index

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sorting with df.index?

`df1.sort_values(by=df2.index, axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: The two dataframes have same data but different index, so I cannot use it to sort

Comment: So the whole dataset is the same? Or only a few columns. If not, you could set multi-column index  on both, sort by df.index, then reset_index.